# sybase ase 15.0.3 64 bit install error

Tags: sybase, 64-bit

I have a 32bit machine installed with 64 bit suse10 linux.
I then tried installing a 64bit sybase on it but the sybase installation fails the moment i launch ./setup with below error:
Searching for Java(tm) Virtual Machine...
........
Running InstallShield Wizard...

An unhandled error occurred -- specify system property "is.debug" for more information.

the install shield wizard fails to launch..

I tried replacing the JVM folder in sybase installation dump but it doesn't help.
how do i use this is:debug property?

has any one encountered such an error?

br
/d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved.
probably due to permissions not available on the dir along the path of install dump or on /tmp.